# Buscar combinação de Palavras em SQL (Redshift)

Tags: sql, text, texto

Caros, boa tarde.

Tenho uma tabela que armazena os textos de mensagens trocadas por e-mail e preciso identificar os e-mails que vem com um conjunto de palavras, por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para toda mensagem que apresentar as combinações ['Mesclado' e 'fechado'], ['mesclado' e 'Fechado'], ['Merged' e 'closed'] identificaria como 1.

Tentei a seguinte query:

```
select distinct
ticket_id,
1 as mesclado 
FROM conversation c 
WHERE
((body_text LIKE ('%Mesclado%') OR body_text LIKE ('%mesclado%')) and body_text LIKE ('%fechado%'))
OR ((body_text LIKE ('%merged%') OR body_text LIKE ('%Merged%')) and body_text LIKE ('%closed%')) 
OR ((body_text LIKE ('%mesclados%') OR body_text LIKE ('%Mesclados%')) and body_text LIKE ('%fechado%'))
```

O resultado esperado seria uma tabela na seguinte configuração:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o resultado que você espera da sua `query`? Adiciona um exemplo prático em http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: O resultado obtido não foi o esperado? Não ficaria mais simples fazer, por exemplo, `WHERE
(lower(body_text) LIKE '%mesclado%' and lower(body_text) LIKE '%fechado%')
OR (lower(body_text) LIKE '%merged%' and lower(body_text) LIKE '%closed%') 
OR (lower(body_text) LIKE '%mesclados%' and lower(body_text) LIKE '%fechado%')`? Ou ainda, dependendo do SGBD utilizado, trabalhar com expressões regulares? Se sempre será listado apenas o campo mesclado com valor 1 por qual motivo lista-lo?

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar um teste direto na query e já trazer o status, pois da forma que está fazendo, não faz sentido algum ter a coluna `mesclado`, e terá que fazer várias consultas para listar todos status, e caso queria, fazer um filtro direto nela.

Consulta trazendo status:

```
SELECT ticket_id,
 (CASE WHEN (body_txt LIKE 'Mesclado e fechado%' OR body_txt LIKE 'Merged and closed%') THEN 1 ELSE
 (CASE WHEN (body_txt LIKE 'Fechado e mesclado%' OR body_txt LIKE 'Closed and merged%') THEN 2 ELSE 3) 
 END) END) as status
FROM conversation
```

Consulta filtrando status:

```
SELECT * FROM 
 (SELECT ticket_id,
     (CASE WHEN (body_txt LIKE 'Mesclado e fechado%' OR body_txt LIKE 'Merged and closed%') THEN 1 ELSE
     (CASE WHEN (body_txt LIKE 'Fechado e mesclado%' OR body_txt LIKE 'Closed and merged%') THEN 2 ELSE 3) 
     END) END) as status
    FROM conversation)
WHERE status = 1
```